# Selecting Columns in DataFrame with Columns Labeled with Period[H] Datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, period

I am trying to show how many people are working in a specific time frame over multiple periods, and would like to display this as a chart using Seaborn.  I'm looking to create something like this:
[image]

My data comes with a single entry per line for each time period, with a start time and end time.  Like so:
[image]

My thought was to create a dataframe with the columns created using period_range `columns = pd.period_range(start=start_datetime, end=end_datetime, freq='H')`, then fill in the relevant cells if that individual worked during that half hour.
This is the complete code:

```
columns2 = pd.period_range(start='2022-01-04 23:00:00', end='2022-01-05 07:00:00', freq='H')
index2 = pd.Index(['Jim', 'John', 'Hannah', 'Clyde'])
hours = pd.DataFrame(index=index2, columns=columns2, data=False)
hours
```

[image]

But I'm having trouble selecting the cells and changing their values.  Any advice how to achieve this, or achieve the goal of the project in general would be greatly appreciated!